# Log4j2.xml configuration doesn't work but log4j2.properties does

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j, log4j2

Hello I have this problem were if i use a log4j2.xml file as a configuration file the logger won't log to console, whereas if i am using a .properties file instead i will have the logs in file.

This is the .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Extra logging related to initialization of Log4j. 
 Set to debug or trace if log4j initialization is failing. -->
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Appenders>
        <!-- Console appender configuration -->
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <!-- Root logger referring to console appender -->
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

.properties file:

```
# Set to debug or trace if log4j initialization is failing
status = warn

# Name of the configuration
name = ConsoleLogConfigDemo

# Console appender configuration
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger level
rootLogger.level = debug

# Root logger referring to console appender
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger
```

(I am trying to do this for a migration from log4j to log4j2 and if i am using the .properties file everything seems to work)

Comment: check documentation https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the properties file and xml file both in resources folder.